# CPU max utilization limited to 1/N CPU’s for MOST multi-threaded Apps on any Win OS : WHY?

Tags: microsoft-excel, cpu, cpu-usage, cpu-architecture

I understand multi-threading and tasking to some extent but know that outside of the OS, most Windows Apps are limited to using only 1/N CPU’s for averaged max. utilization.

That is 50% for a dual core, 25% of 4 CPU and 12.5% of all 8 CPU’s.  This does not change the result if using Procexp.exe to deallocate CPUs or choose even or odd numbered CPUs.

### My question

Is there any way to increase the utilization beyond this OS restricted limit. I understand if one imposed 100% to one App. The OS could blue screen from a non-responding hardware I/O within the expected or required timeout period, but even 50% or 75% would improve my results.

Yet explorer.exe etc in the OS can perform at 50% or more(?) at times when doing large tasks.

- normally the CPU is 98~99.5% idle with just a browser open and 10 tabs ( Brave)

I am using Win7 i7-4770S Haswell 3.1GHz with 16GB RAM on LibreOffice SCALC.exe with a spreadsheet with 1.5 million cells of CV19 US data and did a search/replace the ‘ text prefix to attempt to convert text to a cell number for daily dates (with some options from **text to values**) and it is still running (yes) and obvious I used the wrong method.

If not possible to change OS utilization ratios, then should I rewrite this question on converting 400 text entries to a value of dates ‘1\20\2020 to a value for reformatting to my preference.

- this text file was downloaded from the GitHub repository for JHU CV19 US county daily mortality cumulative totals and imported into SCALC using text to column conversion.

SCALC is still running !” ,  at 12.5% according to PERFMON using 11 threads.

The problem started with a search and replace of 1 character in a 1.5 million cell spreadsheet. I chose "similarity-option" which was a mistake but the problem is not Excel or Open Office Apps , **many apps are multi-threaded but limited to 1/N CPUs on average with no way to change this**. I can prove this with images but some of you will know this to be true.

Others do not understand the question.  yes it is possible to write or for Windows to do this but not canned apps.

EXAMPLE 1  simple startup recovery of a large file process only took seconds and peaked above 20% .  It can peak well over 12.5% avearge for a second but not sustained I supposed when there is a memory thruput limitation.  (SO I guess it nothing can improve this ?)

[image]

Here a search a replace 0 with 0 on 1.5 million cells
Averaged exactly 12.5% just before I captured the screenshot.

[image]

Here almost EXACTLY 1/N or 12.5% of all CPU workload dedicated to 1 Application with many threads.

I can duplicate this test on MANY OTHER APPLICATIONS under Windows with this architecture. So is it architecture - Memory cache bus limited and any fix?

As others have written on this forum, 1/N CPU's limited or 12.50 %

This is the proof.

[image]

More proof on multi-thread MS App i=only using 1/N CPU % average MAX

[image]

### Update

**Installed WordPerfect 2020 with QUattro Pro and ran the exact same multi-threaded process and got exactly THE SAME RESULT
MAX CPU USE on all 8 CPUs = 1/8 = 12.5%**
[image]

### Example #4

- of a multi-threaded process again utilized all CPu's but in total only 1/N CPUs or 12.5% is Mark Russinovich's  Process Explorer ,aka PROCMON.exe. which was independent of all other processes using few resources.

I doubt it was Mark's ability to program multi-threading here. :) (MS Fellow)

[image]
[image]

My CPU Latency is on top
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120780/discussion-on-question-by-tony-stewart-sunnyskyguy-ee75-cpu-max-utilization-limi).

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Any comments will be deleted as comments have been moved to chat. Please do not post any more here.

Comment: I asked you to post in the chat thread. That has nothing to do with your question being a duplicate or otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not all tasks are inherently capable of being split into a task that is able to simultaneously run on every core of the CPU.**

Each core in your CPU is a fully fledged processor. It is able to maintain information on the execution state of one hardware "thread". Each core has its own cache and data handling independent of every other core. They might share a cache and memory bus, but they are otherwise completely separate.

That thread translates roughly to what is known in software as a thread.

The problem you are seeing is that the particular task doing the work within that software is inherently single threaded.

A single thread is only capable of executing on one core at a time. On an 8 core processor that means that a single thread can use at most 1/8th of your processor, or 12.5% according to task manager. On a 4 core processor that is 1/4 or 25%.

A program can have many threads, but those threads can only work on things that are completely unrelated to each other. One thread might be handling updating data being the scenes, another might be updating the GUI and so on.

What threads cannot do is work on the exact same data at the same time without communicating with each other and it is that limit you are seeing.

In order to use more than one CPU core the task being done has to be split up and parcelled out to multiple threads. That splitting up is a programming problem and is down to the software engineers to implement. Whether or not any given task is multithreaded is down to the complexity of that task and whether it can be split up in the first place

- does the task contain data that can be split out into independent data sets in order to be worked on by separate threads?
- has the software been written to split up that particular task into separate threads?

If the data is completely dependent on being worked on in a particular way then there is no way it will ever use more than one core.

If the data can be split up but requires lots more work to split and re-merge then software engineers may decide it is not worth the effort and instead stick to using one thread/core.

If the data can be split up and the software is designed to do so **then** you will see more than 1 core in use.

I know for a number of tasks Excel supports multi-core calculations but it depends entirely on data having absolutely no dependencies on each other.

Comment: TY  for your diligent effort. My spreadsheet had no formulae and thus no dependencies.

Comment: So what are you expecting it to use more CPU for? Just searching the data? Then it is down to whether the programmer thought it worth making that a multi-threaded task, which given the simplicity it probably isn't worth the effort of parcelling out the data for when compared to doing actual work where one calculation might take minutes holding up another that could run at the same time. Programming is a big collection of concessions to what you can do quick, whether it is a benefit to do it another way. Deciding when to use multi-threading is one big cost-benefit analysis problem.

Comment: You might *think* it is easy and "worth it" for your task, but it really isn't. Think about a car. You can have one processor monitoring engine operation, tyre pressures, fuel levels, seat belts and so on. Or you can have 15 processors, each monitoring their own part but then you have to write a program for each processor. The tyre monitors can't check fuel levels and the fuel level monitor can't check seatbelts so you need one "master" processor to bring them all together. That master processor can't simply tell the other processors to check other things they don't understand.

Comment: So if you want *more* tyre monitors you have to add more of them, and now tell each one where their specific data comes from and goes to rather than repurposing one of the others. You can't easily change the entire system architecture "on the fly"  and change 1 tyre monitor into 4 without a lot of work. The same is true of single vs multi-threaded programs. It takes time and effort and money to convert something to work in a different way.

Comment: So the throttle of 1/N CPU’s= Avg CPU max utilization,  is inherent for most multi-threaded Apps because of concurrency issues?  Yet all are multi-CPU shared resources.

Comment: Unless the app is written to access shared resources (like data in memory) from multiple threads then any given task is inherently single threaded. If all you are doing is reading then you need to send off several threads/tasks and give them all different start and end points and then collate their results when they come back, which is a lot more work than just working through the data once (single thread) and making the results list once. For *modifying* data from multiple threads you have the massive headache of ensuring that all tasks are seeing the *right* data that another task modified.

Comment: You are completely missing the point of multiple threads and assuming that all threads run the entire program at the same time and are all capable of the exact same thing. **They don't and they aren't.** Every thread has it's own specific job, and that job is a serial list of things it must do. For each thread that list is inherently single-threaded both in the application and CPU, every step requires knowledge of every step that went before and you cannot "simply" run the same thing a million times and get a million different results without having different start points.

Comment: Yes that makes sense  I had hope the app created memory boundaries to make multiple threads function independently, but I guess the pool is shared at all times

Comment: So only private memory shares might be partitioned from tasks.within one app, which becomes memory inefficient

Comment: It kind of feels like your key assumption is that multi-threading is automatic and an "instant win" situation. But it really isn't. Memory is 100% shared between threads in a process and *is* efficient. A program could have any number of threads accessing the same memory if it wanted to, but it's up to the programmer to make it do that and deal with it properly.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75  FYI Multithreading got implemented in Libreoffive V6 for SCALC - see here https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/69688/how-can-i-make-libreoffice-multi-threaded/

Comment: yes I see it was enabled by default and a move used 25% cpu (copy+delete)  but still takes a few minutes for subtotal at 12.5%